# Unity: How to draw 2D lines directly on a UI canvas?

Tags: unity

The title pretty much tells my issue. I want to simply draw a few lines from a script controlled by start- and endpoint coordinates directly on the UI canvas (so the lines will move at runtime). 
From what I could read up so far, there are these options:

**LineRenderer:**

Works in 3D space. Since I want this on the UI it seems a bit overkill and also to performance hungry for such a simple task. Further, I will have to add a virtual camera and calculate the positions in 3D space (no problems with that part). My data model represents the positions in 2D Pixel coordinates, it would be quite a lot simpler to directly use those coordinates to place the lines on the screen.

**GL.Line():**

Also works in 3D space, furthermore there is no freedom in terms of line thickness.

**Asset Store:**

I tried out a [ui-extension](https://bitbucket.org/UnityUIExtensions/unity-ui-extensions/wiki/Home) package briefly, however it left me with several warnings not connected to the actual functions I used. However if someone knows a lightweight asset, I'm happy to test!

It kind of baffles me that there is nothing provided in Unity for something seemingly so easy. Or am I missing something fundamental here?

Comment: Every "2D" thing you do in Unity is rendered through the 3D pipeline, so don't let 3D be a reason to reject a working solution. Does anything bad happen when you use a LineRenderer for this?

Comment: Oh ok, I just realized I forgot an essential thing to explain. I need the lines to be part of the UI (such as text for example). I'll explain and update my OP.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: ATM I don't have a camera rendering anything. This is for a simple AR app for Vuzix glasses, which takes the camera image and looks for QR Code. Therefore, atm I just have a UI with the decoding result. Now I want to add outlines to the QR-Code

Comment: That sounds like something you can do just fine with a LineRenderer. Where specifically have you run into difficulty making this work?

Comment: OK, with the LineRenderer I will have to add a virtual camera and calculate the positions in 3D space (no problems with that part). However, since my QR-Decoder gives me the position of the code in 2D Pixel coordinates, it would be quite a lot simpler to directly use those coordinates to place the lines on the screen.

Comment: @RolandDeschain When you realize that you forgot to explain something essential, then you might want to update the answer accordingly by editing it. I edited your question to state explicitly that you want a solution for the UI system, but you might want to review my edit in case I misunderstood something.

Comment: Except that Unity's camera gives you a convenience method to turn 2D pixel coordinates into 3D world coordinates, so that should be no obstacle at all.

Comment: @Philipp thanks, was just in the process of doing that. I will check the question again and maybe edit it.

Comment: @DMGregory ok, so it seems there is no way around using the linerenderer. It just seemed obvious to me to draw lines directly on the ui plane...

Comment: There are infinite ways to avoid using the LineRenderer. Are they worth your time? Probably not. You could have a LineRenderer solution up and running in less time than it took to refine this question, and then spend your extra time making the rest of your game/app better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is still relevant, here is a nice tutorial that can show you how to draw a line: https://youtu.be/--LB7URk60A?t=321

Small note that he didn't mention, none of this will work if you don't have a canvas renderer component present on the same gameobject BEFORE you add a Graphic component. You can add a `[RequireComponent(typeof(CanvasRenderer))]` To make sure you always have one before your Graphic script is added.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you included the core steps mentioned in the mentioned source, in order to prevent link rotting.